# I need a dictionary for a custom inspector

Tags: c#, dictionary, serialization, unity-game-engine

So I need a dictionary structure to save things in a custom editor. I know that dictionaries are not allowed so I tried to create my own type, finding out that neither generics are allowed. But List is. So starting from this I have created a class that extends the List and add a small functionality that allows me to treat this object as a Dictionary. Here's the code:

```
public class CustomDictionary : List<CustomDictionaryItem>
 {
     public void Add (string key, UnityEngine.Object value)
     {
         this.Add (new CustomDictionaryItem (key, value));
     }
     public bool ContainsKey (string key)
     {
         return this.Any (sdi => sdi.Key == key);
     }

     public bool Remove (string key)
     {
         return this.RemoveAll (sdi => sdi.Key == key) != 0;
     }
     public UnityEngine.Object this [string key] {
         get {
             if (ContainsKey (key))
                 return (UnityEngine.Object)this.First (sdi => sdi.Key == key).Value;
             return null;
         }
         set {
             if (ContainsKey (key)) {
                 CustomDictionaryItem item = this.First (sdi => sdi.Key == key);
                 item.Value = value;
             } else
                 Add (key, value);
         }
     }
     public List<string> Keys {
         get {
             return this.Select (sdi => sdi.Key).ToList ();
         }
     }
     public List<UnityEngine.Object> Values {
         get {
             return this.Select (sdi => (UnityEngine.Object)sdi.Value).ToList ();
         }
     }
 }
 [Serializable]
 public class CustomDictionaryItem
 {
     [SerializeField]
     private string m_key;
     public string Key{ get { return m_key; } set { m_key = value; } }
     [SerializeField]
     private UnityEngine.Object m_value;
     public UnityEngine.Object Value{ get { return m_value; } set { m_value = value; } }
     public CustomDictionaryItem (string key, UnityEngine.Object value)
     {
         m_key = key;
         m_value = value;
     }
 }
```

I would like it to be typed to be honest(instead of UnityEngine.Object) but I tried to remove the generics in hope that it would work. It doesn't. The values are not saved after the game is started.

PS: this "public List m_customDictionary;" works ok, as it should, but does not have the functionality that I want. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: whe are dictionarys not allowed?

Comment: @lordkain Unity hasn't provided editor support for them.

Comment: Unity's serialization module doesn't support polymorphism -- it will serialize fields associated with the base type, but won't deserialize correctly. A more common workaround is to serialize supported types, then stitch together a dictionary at game start.

Comment: that's a good solution, but quite expensive and besides that most of the dictionary's functionality is needed in the editor scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Unity has a problem recognizing this class is derived from List. As a workaround I would suggest making List a member instead of deriving. If you want to be able to iterate over CustomDictionary, you can add GetEnumerator() method that simply returns List GetEnumerator().

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomDictionary
{
    [SerializeField]
    private List<CustomDictionaryItem> l;

    public void Add (string key, UnityEngine.Object value)
    {
        l.Add (new CustomDictionaryItem (key, value));
    }
    public bool ContainsKey (string key)
    {
        return l.Any (sdi => sdi.Key == key);
    }

    public bool Remove (string key)
    {
        return l.RemoveAll (sdi => sdi.Key == key) != 0;
    }
    public UnityEngine.Object this [string key] {
        get {
            if (ContainsKey (key))
                return (UnityEngine.Object)l.First (sdi => sdi.Key == key).Value;
            return null;
        }
        set {
            if (ContainsKey (key)) {
                CustomDictionaryItem item = l.First (sdi => sdi.Key == key);
                item.Value = value;
            } else
                Add (key, value);
        }
    }
    public List<string> Keys {
        get {
            return l.Select (sdi => sdi.Key).ToList ();
        }
    }
    public List<UnityEngine.Object> Values {
        get {
            return l.Select (sdi => (UnityEngine.Object)sdi.Value).ToList ();
        }
    }

    public List<CustomDictionaryItem>.Enumerator GetEnumerator() {
        return l.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

EDIT: After giving it some thought, there is a way to make this dictionary generic. It is ugly, I even feel a bit ashamed for writing such code, but it will work.

Here is the trick:
Unity will not present generic classes in editor. But it has no problem with classes that derive from generic classes. So the idea is to create a dummy non generic dictionary that is derived from `GenericDictionary`. Same about `GenericDictionaryItem`, we will create non generic dummy that simply derives from the generic one.

This is the basic idea. Here are the pitfalls:

It would be ideal if we could define the dummy derived from `GenericDictionaryItem` as `GenericDictionary` subclass. It turns out we can't. Unity will not show such classes in the editor. So the solution I used here is to manually create an `Entry` type that must derive from `GenericDictionaryItem`, and pass it as the third `GenericDictionary` generic argument, in addition to Key and Value.

Next, in C# we cannot use generic type `Entry` non default constructor. So the solution I used for this is to add `SetKV(key, value)` method to `GenericDictionaryItem`, that can be used as a constructor. `Entry` will use only the default constructor. Maybe a more elegant solution would be to use some factory object, I just made it quick.

Last, pay attention that **you cannot compare generic keys with `==`, must use `Equals(Object)`**. It is important to remember, since equals default implementation for reference type is **reference comparison**. So it will work fine with value types (int, Color, Vector3 ...), and also with strings, but you must implement `Equals` for reference key types such as `GameObject` if you decide to use `GameObject` as a key. C# `Dictionary` provides `IEqualityComparer` for such cases, here I didn't provide it, but you can do it if you really want.

Finally, the code is:

```
[Serializable]
public class GenericDictionaryItem<K, V>
{
    [SerializeField]
    private K m_key;
    public K Key{ get { return m_key; } set { m_key = value; } }
    [SerializeField]
    private V m_value;
    public V Value{ get { return m_value; } set { m_value = value; } }
    public GenericDictionaryItem (K key, V value)
    {
        m_key = key;
        m_value = value;
    }

    public GenericDictionaryItem () : this (default(K), default(V)) {
    }

    // In C# we cannot use non default constructor with types passed as generic argument.
    // So as a workaround we will use this function instead of constructor.
    internal void SetKV(K key, V value) {
        m_key = key;
        m_value = value;
    }
}
[Serializable]
// Generic arguments: K - key type, V - value type, Entry - must be a class derived from
// GenericDictionaryItem<K, V> and implementing a default constructor.
// K must implement Equals method!
public class GenericDictionary<K, V, Entry> where Entry : GenericDictionaryItem<K, V>, new()
{

    [SerializeField]
    private List<Entry > l;

    public void Add (K key, V value)
    {
        // Cannot use non default constructor with generic type.
        // This is a workaround
        var e = new Entry();
        e.SetKV(key, value);

        l.Add (e);
    }
    public bool ContainsKey (K key)
    {
        return l.Any (sdi => sdi.Key.Equals(key));
    }

    public bool Remove (K key)
    {
        return l.RemoveAll (sdi => sdi.Key.Equals(key)) != 0;
    }
    public V this [K key] {
        get {
            if (ContainsKey (key))
                return (V)l.First (sdi => sdi.Key.Equals(key)).Value;
            return default(V);
        }
        set {
            if (ContainsKey (key)) {
                Entry item = l.First (sdi => sdi.Key.Equals(key));
                item.Value = value;
            } else
                Add (key, value);
        }
    }
    public List<K> Keys {
        get {
            return l.Select (sdi => sdi.Key).ToList ();
        }
    }
    public List<V> Values {
        get {
            return l.Select (sdi => (V)sdi.Value).ToList ();
        }
    }

    public List<Entry>.Enumerator GetEnumerator() {
        return l.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

// Test class
public class DictionaryTest : MonoBehaviour {

    // Create dummy entry type
    [Serializable]
    public class Entry : GenericDictionaryItem<string, UnityEngine.Object> {
    }

    // Create dummy dictionary type
    // Pay attention - we pass 3 arguments key type, value type and entry type
    [Serializable]
    public class MyDictionary : GenericDictionary<string, UnityEngine.Object, Entry> {
    }

    // And now we will see the dictionary in editor
    public MyDictionary d;

    void Start() {

        d.Add("test1", null);
        d.Add("test2", null);

        Debug.Log(d.ContainsKey("test1"));
        Debug.Log(d.ContainsKey("test2"));
        Debug.Log(d.ContainsKey("test3"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried something like this but it doesn't work. Unity does not serialize generic members for some reason. Ref: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/214300/serializable-class-using-generics.html

Comment: Unity does not serialize generic members, unless it is generic List. There is no problem writing [SerializeField] List<SerializableType> myList, you will see it in the inspector as an array. I checked the code above, and it was working.

Comment: You are right. The thing is I tried this but apparently I missed something because it wasn't working. Probably some attributes. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @yura-nudelman, Is there any chance to create this CustomDictionary a generic one?

Comment: Well, seems there is a way. I edited the answer above, please have a look.

Comment: Stupid unity. Ugly solution but it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Though a bit late, I just found this ***free*** asset in the Unity Asset Store. It was added around the time of version 4.7. It is [SerializableDictionary](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/serializabledictionary-90477).
A serializable dictionary class for Unity.

From the store:

Unity is not able to serialize native dictionaries. Use this class in your scripts to expose dictionaries in the inspector.

- Derives from Dictionary
- Use any serializable type as key or value
- No need to create custom inspectors

My plan is to see if it still works. My thought is that it gives us a start from which to build.